# Composing F# code quotations programmatically

Tags: linq, f#, expression, quotations

The following code is extracted from an application and adapted to highlight the issue as easy as possible

```
module Mo

open System
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers
open System.Linq.Expressions

type Type() = 
    member _.Prop1 with get() = 1
    member _.Prop2 with get() = 2

let toFunc<'t when 't :> Type>(filter: 't -> Expr<bool>) =
    let xp = <@ Func<'t, bool>(fun (t: 't) -> %(filter t) && t.Prop2 = 2) @>
    LeafExpressionConverter.QuotationToExpression xp |> unbox<Expression<Func<'t, bool>>>

let getFunc (i: int) = 
    let filter (t: Type) = <@ t.Prop1 = i @>
    toFunc filter
```

the problem is in the line

```
let xp = <@ Func< 't, bool>(fun (t: 't) -> %(filter t) && t.Prop2 = 2) @>
```

The compiler complains in *fun (**t**: 't)* as follows:

```
Error   FS0446  
The variable 't' is bound in a quotation but is used as part of a spliced expression.
This is not permitted since it may escape its scope.
```

The intent is to compose quotations into a filter Linq expression.
Is there a (alternative) way to do this?

**EDIT**:

Some more context looks necessary:

The returned Func expression is later passed to Azure.Data.Tables.TableClient.Query(). Unfortunately this method doesn't support expressions containing function calls.

Converting *filter* to a quoted function (as suggested by Fyodor) was my first version, but I had to abandon it because of this requirement of the Azure Tables SDK.

So the question becomes :

Is it possible to achieve the result of an expression that doesn't contain calls to external method/function?

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing up your variables between quotation realm and "regular" realm.

`filter` is not a quoted function. It's a regular function that returns a quotation. Regular functions get regular parameters, quoted functions get quoted parameters.

The `t` parameter here:

```
let xp = <@ Func<'t, bool>(fun (t: 't) -> %(filter t) && t.Prop2 = 2) @>
                                ^
                                |
                             This one
```

That's a quoted parameter. It's defined inside a quotation.

And yet, you're trying to pass its value to the `filter` function. But at the moment of constructing the quotation, the parameter `t` doesn't have a value yet! Only when you're done constructing the quotation, then compile it to IL, and then call it, - only then will the parameter `t` have a value, allowing you to call the `filter` function. But you need the result of `filter` function to finish constructing the quotation in the first place!

The most straightforward fix is to make `filter` a quoted function. Then you can splice it into the quotation, and then pass the parameter `t` to the result of splicing:

```
let toFunc<'t when 't :> Type>(filter: Expr<'t -> bool>) =
    let xp = <@ Func<'t, bool>(fun (t: 't) -> (%filter) t && t.Prop2 = 2) @>
    LeafExpressionConverter.QuotationToExpression xp |> unbox<Expression<Func<'t, bool>>>

let getFunc (i: int) = 
    let filter = <@ fun (t: Type) -> t.Prop1 = i @>
    toFunc filter
```